# How do I execute Maya script without lauching Maya?

Tags: scripting, maya, mel

For example, I want to launch a script that creates a poly cube, export it to .stl or .fbx from the command line.

I can do it in Python by using the Maya standalone but it cannot handle exporting to other formats than .ma apparently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why of course you can. Here's how you'd do exactly that (for FBX):

```
from os.path import join

from maya.standalone import initialize
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel

initialize("python")
cmds.loadPlugin("fbxmaya")
my_cube = cmds.polyCube()
cmds.select(my_cube[0], r=True)

my_filename = "cube2.fbx"
my_folder = "C:/SomeFolder/scenes"
full_file_path = join(my_folder, my_filename).replace('\\', '/')

mel.eval('FBXExport -f "%s"' % full_file_path)
```

Hope that was useful.

Comment: Thanks very much ! Do you know if we can launch MEL from command line or it is launched only within Maya ?

Comment: Yes you can. in your command prompt:

`maya -prompt`

This will start maya in command prompt mode. You can type in MEL commands here.

Please vote up or accept the answers that you found useful. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and it works if we load also the plugin OneClick. This is maybe specific to my Maya version (2015 Mac). Thanks again !