# How to execute Maya python scripts in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, maya, houdini

I'm writing some simple pipeline scripts for my company.
I did lots of houdini work in pycham and it works as expected:
When you work in houdini python interpreter it is like working in houdini without UI.
BUT, with Maya I cant get anything working inside PyCharm, I have to execute everything in Maya using MayaCharm plug in.
Completition works, imports work, but whatever I do, whatever function, methods, .. I call I'm always getting 'None' as results.
Not errors, just 'None' as result.
I tried solution from: [How do I execute Maya script without lauching Maya?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27018520/how-do-i-execute-maya-script-without-lauching-maya) but it also don't work.
Result of "my_cube = cmds.polyCube()" is "None".
Even if I just call cmds.ls() I'm getting "None"
Any help or ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you launching your script with mayapy, you might wanna initialize maya first:
https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/PyMel/standalone.html

```
import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize(name='python')
import maya.cmds as cmds
```

If you trying to launch something from PyCharm right in the live Maya session, then MayaCharm is they way to go I believe.

Comment: Did that.
In mayapy maya.cmds, maya.api.<whatever> worked always. problem was that I couldn't import hou.
Now I reinstaled everything and (I don't know where from) under interpreter paths there was "C:\Program Files\Side Effects Software\Houdini 16.5.268\houdini\python2.7libs" and import hou works.
I probably messed up something with paths. When I have more time I'll try to find out what are exact steps and will post them here.
Now I'm a happy camper, having maya and houdini under one interpreter so I can write few maya->houdini scene parsing scripts that I need. :)

Comment: I'm not sure how everyone doing that, but taking into account broken state of Maya out of box completion for Python I decided to go radical way and made a separate 'development' PyCharm environment where all the pymel, cmds, and openmaya specially prepared completion files reside. Very handy.

To run my scripts in working environment I'm just using Maya itself or mayapy, or even system Python27 with sys.path set to Maya site-packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute in Maya but use Pycharm as an editor, you should probably just use [MayaCharm](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8218-mayacharm), which is designed precisely for that purpose.